# Как сделать декодер и енкодер с нуля

Tags: python

И так, как мне из этой строчки `Learn english please!` каждую букву первую букву сдвинуть налево 13раз а каждую вторую букву направо 7 раз, и как при получении закодированного текста этим скриптом расшифровать его?

Comment: сдвинуть налево по словарю?

Comment: @Zhihar -, по англ алфавиту, даже если текст на русском

Comment: а как вы хотите русские буквы смещать по английскому алфавиту - как это выглядеть должно?

Comment: а, так нельзя, тогда олни англ алфавт

Comment: ну тогда и русские буквы не будут обработаны

Comment: хорошо, можете показать пример? @Zhihar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

алгоритм:

1. идти по позиции в строке от `0` до `len(text)`
2. четную и нечётную позицию буквы проверять через `pos % 2 == 0`
3. найти позицию буквы в словаре через `dictionary.index(letter)`, где словарь содержит все буквы английского алфавита
4. вычислить новую позицию через `pos_new = (pos_old + shift + len(dictionary)) % pos_old + shift + len(dictionary)` - такой подход сделан чтобы и отрицательные позиции корректно обрабатывать
5. извлечь букву в словаре по новой позиции и заменить старую (или собрать новую строку)

при расшифровке просто менять знак у смещения влево или вправо

```
dictionary = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ! '

#    ENCODE
def encode(text):
  encoded = ''
  left = 13
  right = 7
  
  for pos in range(len(text)):
    index = dictionary.index(text[pos])
    if pos % 2 == 0:
      index = (index + right + len(dictionary)) % len(dictionary)
    else:
      index = (index - left + len(dictionary)) % len(dictionary)
    encoded += dictionary[index]
    
  return encoded

#    DECODE
def decode(encoded_text):
  decoded = ''
  left = 13
  right = 7
  
  for pos in range(len(encoded_text)):
    index = dictionary.index(encoded_text[pos])
    if pos % 2 == 0:
      index = (index - right + len(dictionary)) % len(dictionary)
    else:
      index = (index + left + len(dictionary)) % len(dictionary)
    decoded += dictionary[index]
  return decoded
```

Comment: ? немного не понял, можно пример плиз(

Comment: добавил код для примера загифровки

Comment: что за `dictionary`? "dictionary" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable
dictionary: Any

Comment: я же написал выше - это словарь английских букв `dictionary = 'abcdef...'`

Comment: аа, мне нужна переменная dictionary с англ буквами по алфавиту с нижнего регистра?

Comment: да - и это будет работать с текстами, которые содержат тоже только английские буквы, пробел не забудьте добавить в словарь, а хотите русские или большие буквы или цифры - добавить и их

Comment: работает, а можно пример как сделать энкодер?

Comment: как я написал с энкодером - вам вместо `+7` и `-13` надо сделать `-7` и `+13`